# Adding get_context_data method to a class based view breaks django-tables2

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-tables2

I have a class-based view that I use to obtain a queryset and pass to django-tables2 which renders the result. That aspect all works fine. I am trying to pass a record instance from a different queryset to the template, so I can display information above the table django-tables2 produces.

Upon searching, it seems the 'right' way to do so is via the `get_context_data` method. However when I attempt do add this method to my view, simply obtaining the queryset and returning it, it produces an error `Expected table or queryset, not str`. I isolated this to being due to  `{% render_table table %}` in my template. Without that, I can access my 'team' object as intended.

Why is this happening? The qs queryset was being passed fine to django-tables2 before I added my get_context_data method. Does the qs queryset have to be returned via get_context_data as well? If so, why?

This is my attempt:

```
class myteam(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Contestant.objects.filter(assigned_team=self.request.user.contestant.assigned_team)
        qs = qs.exclude(id=self.request.user.contestant.id)
        return qs
    
    def get_template_names(self):
        return 'xgames/viewteam.html'

    def get_table_class(self):
        return TeamsTable 
        
    def get_context_data(self):
        team = Team.objects.get(id=self.request.user.contestant.assigned_team.id)
        return {"team": team}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like you forgot to call the super() method

```
class myteam(LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableView):
    # Rest of the code

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context["team"] = Team.objects.get(
            id=self.request.user.contestant.assigned_team.id
        )
        return context
```